# cannot call method with null arguments c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method with parameters and i want to call it in my global application class, but when i pass null arguments it will give an error. I'm sharing my code please guide me.

Method:

```
public static async Task getMessage(Controller page,string Email, int? PersonId, int? OrderDetailId, int? TicketDetailId)
    {
        using (var client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", true))
        {      
            // Connecting
            if (client.Connect())
            {
                // Sign in
                if (client.Login("abc@gmail.com", "*****"))
                {

                    var excludeLabels = new string[] { "Processed" };
                    var senders = new string[] { Email };

                    // Building the search query
                    var query = string.Format("X-GM-RAW \"{0} -({1})\"",
                                                    string.Join(" OR ", senders.Select(sender => "(from:" + sender + ")")),
                                                    string.Join(" OR ", excludeLabels.Select(label => "(label:" + label + ")")));

                    var messages = client.Folders.Inbox.Search(query, MessageFetchMode.ClientDefault, 1000);

                    foreach (var msg in messages)
                    {
                        // Mark the message as seen
                        msg.Seen = true;
                        string plainTextBody = msg.Body.HasText ? msg.Body.Text : "";
                        string htmlBody = msg.Body.HasHtml ? msg.Body.Html : "";

                        var time = DateTime.SpecifyKind(msg.Date.HasValue ? msg.Date.Value : DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc);

                        if (msg.Attachments.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var file in msg.Attachments)
                            {
                                var folder = Server.MapPath("~/Data/ConversationAttachments");
                                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                                }
                                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                                string webPath = null;
                                msg.Download(MessageFetchMode.Full);
                                int posOfDot = file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".");
                                string fName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + file.FileName.Substring(posOfDot);
                                webPath = "~/Data/ConversationAttachments/" + fName;
                                file.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Data/ConversationAttachments"), fName);

                                db.MailSystems.AddOrUpdate(c => c.MESSAGEID, new MailSystem
                                {
                                    Message = htmlBody,
                                    Date = time,
                                    Attachment = webPath,
                                    EmailType = "IMAP",
                                    Subject = string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg.Subject) ? "RE: Ticket ID " + TicketDetailId.Value.ToString() : msg.Subject,
                                    Sender = Email,
                                    PersonID = PersonId.Value,
                                    TicketDetailId = TicketDetailId.Value,
                                    MESSAGEID = msg.MessageId
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Global Application Class:

```
        protected void ThreadFunc()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
            t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerWorker);
            t.Interval = 10000;
            t.Enabled = true;
            t.AutoReset = true;
            t.Start();
        }

        protected void TimerWorker(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

           GetMail.getMessage();
        }
```

getMessage method is a static member of static GetMail class. Please guide me how i can solve this issue. I want to start the getMessage method automatically after every 30 seconds.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla error is getMessage() requires 5 arguments

Comment: Then pass it 5 arguments.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla i have tried calling this method using reflection but it is not giving any error but not calling the method

Comment: Where do you even use the getMessage here? Just a note. You should name your method names with Upper case like `GetMessage()`

Comment: @CodeCaster i cannot pass 5 arguments from global application class

Comment: You have to. The method expects them.

Comment: @Dejan.S i want this getMessage() method to run automatically after 30 seconds

Comment: @Usama Why do you pass in a `Controller` in the method?

Comment: You want to call a method that does something with the parameters you pass it (it _needs_ the email, order ID, and so on) without passing those parameters. You **cannot do that**. You need to re-think your design.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your code attempts to call other methods and properties on the nullable types that are passed into your method.

I.e.

```
PersonId.Value
TicketDetailId.Value
```

If you want to have nullable arguments in your method signature *and* be able to pass null values for those arguments, you need to fix your code so it works with those arguments being null.

In short, there's no obvious answer here, you can't pass in null arguments and expect to be able to use their properties and methods without encountering an exception.

Your usual solutions are, pass in types that can't be null:

```
public void MyMethod(int myValue)
```

Or do a null check before:

```
if (myThing == null)
{
    return;
}
```

Or:

```
if (myThing != null)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Or apply the '??' operator to apply a default value if null:

```
string myResult = myThing ?? string.Empty;
```

**EDIT**

Your other problem is that you're calling the `getMessage()` method with no parameters.  The signature of `getMessage` looks like:

```
getMessage(Controller page, string email, int? personId, int? orderDetailId, int? ticketDetailId)
```

(Note I've lowercased the first letter of your argument names, as per typical C# standards)

You should be passing some parameters when calling it:

```
getMessage("myPage", "test@hotmail.com", 2, 37, 92);
```

You need to understand a lot more about the very basics of C# and Object Oriented programming in general.  Try reading some introductory books on C# development.

Comment: thanks for the help, i have changed the timerwork method to this "protected void TimerWorker(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            object[] arguments = new object[5];
            MethodInfo method = typeof(GetMail).GetMethod("getMessage");
            method.Invoke(null, arguments);
        }"
error is gone but method is not executing

Answer (score 0):

```
GetMail.getMessage();
```

Doesnt work, because there aren't a method with these signature. the parameters can be null (int**?**), but they aren't optional..

Change to:

```
GetMail.getMessage(null, null, null, null, null);
```

Or create a new method with no parameters... and then call your method

```
public static void getMessage()
{
    GetMessage(null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Or set default values

```
public static void getMessage(Person page = null, string Email ="", int? PersonId =0, int? OrderDetailId=0, int? TicketDetailId=0) { ... }
```

It will work... but.. it is a creepy code :-)

Comment: is there any other way to call this method after every 30 seconds

Comment: is there any way to call this method through a wcf service?

Comment: oh.. I've got a notion that you have a console application. WCF service is a service to get data... not for start some "timerjobs"